# Riemann Sum proofs

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\lvert f(x) \rvert$ $\le$ $M$ for all $x$ $\epsilon [a,b]$, show that:

> $\lvert \int_a^b f \rvert$ $\le$ $M(b-a)$

Just started learning Riemann sums and integrability proofs, and am having trouble approaching proofs like these.

Comment: Was the integral defined a la Darboux or as a limit ? In every case you need not know that $|f|$ is integrable.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\left|\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x) dx\right| \leq \displaystyle \int_{a}^b |f(x)|dx$